# MFC - edit File-Open action

Tags: c++, mfc

I created a MFC application using the MFC app wizard, with the SDI template. Currently, everything is unchanged. So all my classes are the ones generated by the wizard, straight-forward.

Now I want to edit what the File->Open... menu does. 
Where do I edit this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't already have one add a message handler in your app class, like this in the message map:

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, OnMyFileOpen)

void CXXApp::OnMyFileOpen()
{
...
}
```

Comment: But when I click the File->Open it already opens the dialog, so this should already be implemented somewhere?

Comment: The dialog is opened by CWinAppEx::OnFileOpen(), which is the default handler for the above message.

Comment: allright! and so, my callback must call the open dialog by itself right?

Comment: Whatever. You can call CWinAppEx::OnFileOpen() if you like.

Comment: Ok now I understand what was going on. It creates a callback with CWinAppEx::OnFileOpen() by default. I had to remove that callback first. (maybe there was a better way of doing this, taking advantage of some return code from the default ` CWinAppEx::OnFileOpen()` but whatever)